# Copper CRM Webhooks - where i need to place webhooks to get notifications on events?

Tags: laravel, crm

i am using  a Laravel setup to get webhooks from Copper CRM side. they provided this link.

https://developer.copper.com/#b22d5c44-038c-4089-b202-86bcc3058788

basically i need to get notifications on a specific site whenever Update event occurs on Opportunity on CRM. here is the code for that webhook provided in documentation.

```
{
  "ids": [<entity_id_1>, <entity_id_2>, ...],
  "type": "<entity_type>",
  "event": "<event_type>",
  "subscription_id": <subscription_id>,
  "secret_field_1": "<string>",
  "secret_field_2": "<string>",
  "updated_attributes": {
    "field_name": [<old_value>, <new_value>]
  }
}
```

where i need to place this code to be executed ?? on Copper site? but where? any help any tutorials ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to receive notifications you must subscribe to copper by sending the endpoint where you want to receive the information, here I leave you the detailed documentation that can help you

https://support.copper.com/hc/en-us/articles/217214766-Learn-more-about-Copper-Webhooks